# Collatz function in scheme

Tags: scheme, collatz

So i'm trying to solve the collatz function iteratively in scheme but my test cases keep showing up as

```
(define (collatz n)   
    (define (collatz-iter n counter)
            (if (<=  n 1)
                1
            (if (even? n)  (collatz-iter (/ n 2) (+ counter 1))
                           (collatz-iter (+ (* n 3) 1) (+ counter 1)) 
            )
            )
    )
)
```

However, my test cases keep resulting in "#[constant 13 #x2]". What did I write wrong, if anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to call `collatz-iter`. Also, it's not clear what do you intend to do with `counter`, you just increment it, but never actually use its value - your procedure will *always* return `1` (assuming that the Collatz conjecture is true, which seems quite possible).

I'm guessing you intended to return the counter, so here's how to fix your procedure:

```
(define (collatz n)
  (define (collatz-iter n counter)
    (if (<= n 1)
        counter ; return the counter
        (if (even? n)
            (collatz-iter (/ n 2) (+ counter 1))
            (collatz-iter (+ (* n 3) 1) (+ counter 1)))))
  (collatz-iter n 1)) ; call collatz-iter
```

And this is how it works for the examples in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Examples):

```
(collatz 6)
=> 9

(collatz 11)
=> 15

(collatz 27)
=> 112
```

So basically we're counting the length of the Collatz sequence for a given number.

Answer (score 4):

You should indent your code properly.  With proper formatting, it's

```
(define (collatz n)   
  (define (collatz-iter n counter)
    (if (<=  n 1)
        1
        (if (even? n)
            (collatz-iter (/ n 2) (+ counter 1))
            (collatz-iter (+ (* n 3) 1) (+ counter 1))))))
```

which clearly has no body forms to execute, just an internal definition.  You need to add a call to `collatz-iter`, like this:

```
(define (collatz n)   
  (define (collatz-iter n counter)
    (if (<=  n 1)
        1
        (if (even? n)
            (collatz-iter (/ n 2) (+ counter 1))
            (collatz-iter (+ (* n 3) 1) (+ counter 1)))))
  (collatz-iter n 1))
```

(I'm not sure what your initial `counter` value should be.  I'm assuming `1` is reasonable, but perhaps it should be zero?) Better yet, since the body it just a call to `collatz-iter`, you can make this a named let, which is more like your original code:

```
(define (collatz n)
  (let iter ((n n) (counter 1))
    (if (<=  n 1)
        1
        (if (even? n)
            (iter (/ n 2) (+ counter 1))
            (iter (+ (* n 3) 1) (+ counter 1))))))
```

It's sort of like combining the internal definition with the single call to the local function.  Once you've done this, though, you'll see that it always returns `1`, when it eventually gets to the base case (assuming the Collatz conjecture is true, of course).  Fixing this, you'll end up with:

```
(define (collatz n)
  (let iter ((n n) (counter 1))
    (if (<=  n 1)
        counter
        (if (even? n)
            (iter (/ n 2) (+ counter 1))
            (iter (+ (* n 3) 1) (+ counter 1))))))
```

Comment: Oh! I meant to put the call to collatz-iter back in but i must have just blanked. I'm also confused now as to why my test cases are all reading as 1, since im trying to count the steps to the answer and not the answer itself

Comment: @user2789945 See the code at the end of my answer, as well as the comment "Once you've done this, though, you'll see that it always returns 1, when it eventually gets to the base case (assuming the Collatz conjecture is true, of course). Fixing this, you'll end up with: …"

Answer (score 3):

When I try to run your code in Racket I get the error:

> no expression after a sequence of internal definitions

This is telling us that the `collatz` function conatains the `collatz-iter` definition, but no expression to call it (other than the recursive calls in `collatz-iter`).  That can be fixed by adding a call to `(collatz-iter n 0)` as the last line in `collatz`.

However, when you run the program it always returns 1.  Not very interesting.  If instead you change it to return the value of `counter` you can see how many steps it took for the sequence to reach 1.

```
(define (collatz n)   
    (define (collatz-iter n counter)
            (if (<=  n 1)
                counter
            (if (even? n)  (collatz-iter (/ n 2) (+ counter 1))
                           (collatz-iter (+ (* n 3) 1) (+ counter 1)) 
            )
            )
    )
  (collatz-iter n 0)
)
```

We can check it against a few examples given on the Wikipedia [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) article.

```
> (collatz 6)
8
> (collatz 11)
14
> (collatz 27)
111
>
```